# Can not authorize DHCP server

Tags: windows-server-2003, dhcp, dhcp-server

I have run into a strange DHCP problem. The thing is the service is running, but the DHCP is not authorized. However, when I try to do it by right clicking, the option to authorize is not there - I can only choose to unathorize it. (Sorry, can't includa a SS).

When I click unauthorize, I get the error "The parameter is incorrect." So now I'm stuck with unauthorized DHCP server that for some reason only can be authorized. I have tried all the usual stuff except re-installing the service. Anyone here have a clue what it can be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried to unauthorize DHCP-server this way? >>

- Open ***DHCP*** snap-in.
- In the console tree, click ***DHCP***.
- On the ***Action*** menu, click ***Manage authorized servers***.
- The Manage Authorized Servers dialog box appears.
- In ***Authorized DHCP*** servers, select the server you want to unauthorize.
- Click ***Unauthorize***.

Comment: Tried it and while I can click both unauthorize and authorize without error, the result is sitll the same - the DHCP server stays unauthorized. checking Event Viewer, I get the following error: "The DHCP service failed to see a directory server for authorization."

Comment: Looks like DHCP-server doesn't see your DC. Firewall/connection/DNS issue? Does DHCP reside on the same machine there the AD DS is installed? Is DC available at all?

Comment: Yes, this is the first server and it's all on the same machine.

Comment: Restart DHCP server from DHCP mmc. Then check if the server can be authorized. My guess is that DHCP server starts before Active Directory starts. Is this W2k8 machine?

Comment: Still no luck. It's a 2003, as my tag should show.

Comment: Run "dcdiag /test:DNS" to see if DNS is functioning properly. Since this can't be connectivity issue, then there're issues with name resolution.

Comment: HA! Seems like the NETLOGON service had been paused for some reason. Now it works. Thanks for your time.